# Install ubuntu on macbook pro 11,2 with retina display

Tags: 12.04, 13.04, macbook

How can I install ubuntu on macbook pro 11,2 (late 2013) with retina display. Have searched on other forums but did not get answers.

Preferred would be Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

Comment: check this https://help.ubuntu.com/community/How%20to%20install%20Ubuntu%20on%20MacBook%20using%20USB%20Stick

Answer (score 0):

i do have the exact same question, but i doubt that anyone has an answer to that yet. (at least for 12.04 LTS)

check out http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2184760
and https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MacBookPro11-1/Saucy 
for 13.04

i tried installing 12.04 but i do get black screen after selecting "Try Ubuntu" or "Install Ubuntu" (i do have the 15 inch iris pro model)
maybe i'm gonna look into that a little bit more..

Answer (score 0):

you need to add boot parameters if you are getting stuck with a black screen or purple screen . 
Hit the corresponding function key for the boot options and set 'nomodeset' , 'nolapic' , 'noacpi'

And then boot .